# Can not Increase stringsize of Production Pool column in Dynamics-AX 4.0

Tags: axapta, ax

Tried increasing the production pool id size , but the property is grayed out, I am in the admin group, how ever I am not sure that this is either group rights or something else as I can modify many other properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exteded data type `ProdPoolId` extends from `PoolId` which extends from `SysGroup` which has a string size of 10.

You cannot change the string size of `ProdPoolId`or `PoolId` without breaking the inheritance.

This is probably what you should do for the `PoolId`, remove the `SysGroup` then set the string size to what you want. This will change `PurchPoolId` and `SalesPoolId` as well.

If you choose to change only `ProdPoolId`, go ahead, just ensure that there is no variable assignments from a ProdPoolId to a PoolId, as this would result in string truncation.

I would not recommend changing size of `SysGroup` as this will change thousands of fields.

Comment: Ok, them it is setteled, not changing the id! Thank you Jan.